# Editing a KendoTemplate in Jquery function

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-mvvm, kendo-template

I am using Kendo Mvvm to create a template for items I am getting from a data source.  What I would like to do is have a visible binding in my template that I can toggle on in off for the specific template that is being clicked on but I cant get it to work.

HTML place for Template:

```
<ul id="memberlistview" data-template="memberSelectTemplate" data-bind="source: allmembers" style="color: #333333; float: left; padding: 0"></ul>
```

HTML Template:

```
 <script id="memberSelectTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div style="float: left; height: 55px; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 5px; background-color: white" data-bind="click: addmember">
       <div style="float: left; width: 40px; height: 55px; padding: 5px;" data-bind="visible: selecteduser">
            <img src="~/Images/imgCheck-blue.png" />
        </div>
        <img data-bind="attr: { src: userpic}" style="float: left; width: 55px; height: 55px; border-radius: 5px;">
        <h3 style="float: left" class="item-title" data-bind="text: userdisplayname"></h3>
        <div style="display: none" data-bind="text: userid"></div>
        <div style="display: none" data-bind="text: useradid"></div>
        <div style="display: none" username></div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Jquery to set Template:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: MobileHomePath + "GetAllUsers",
}).success(function (data) {
    vm.set("allmembers", [])
    if (data != null && data != "") {
        var count = 0;
        $.each(data, function () {
            vm.get("allmembers").push({
                selecteduser: false,
                userpic: data[count].Pic,
                userdisplayname: data[count].DisplayName,
                username: data[count].UserName,
                userid: data[count].Id,
                useradid: data[count].AdId,
            });
            count = count + 1;
        });
    }
});
```

Jquery to try and change Template:

```
    addmember: function (e) {
      e.data.selecteduser = true;
    },
    allmembers: [
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the HTML to be updated, you should use the observable object set method instead of direct assignment - 
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/observableobject#methods-set